# Mac mini display tinted purple

Tags: macos, display, mac-mini

Yesterday I was using my Mac mini as usual when the power went out.
When I was able to turn it on again, I noticed that the screen image was tinted in purple, as if the display color profile was miscalibrated.

I've already checked the VGA cable, and it is well attached in both ends.

This had happened months ago after when the power had gone out as well. But that time the screen was greenish rather than purplish. It seemed to fix itself after some days.

Does anyone knows what is the cause of it and how to solve it?

**Update:** I've managed to get another monitor to test, and looks it that's the issue. Gotta find a new one now :(

**Update 2:** today, again I had a power failure here, and after that the monitor is working fine again. But anyway, I'd better get a new one.

Comment: Just to make sure - you didn't have anything like [f.lux](http://justgetflux.com/) running?

Comment: No, any app that could interfere with the screen colors is installed.

Comment: What kind of screen do you have? Any screen close which you could attach and check the colors?

Comment: It's a quite simple 15" Dell, VGA only, I don't know what model. I don't have any other display here to test today, but I'll see if I can find one.

Comment: check the settings of your dell monitor - they usually have a menu where you can set tint and so on. Maybe some setting screwed up

Comment: No, the settings are fine. In fact, I've tuned them to reduce the purple tint, but there's no way to get even close to what it should look like.